# How can I use checkinstall to replace multiple packages?

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, ffmpeg, checkinstall

I'm building my own `ffmpeg` package using `checkinstall`, with all of the various `ffmpeg` libraries included. In the Ubuntu package repos these ffmpeg libraries are broken up into many separate packages. Is there any way to tell apt/dpkg that all of these requirements are satisfied by my ffmpeg package. That way, for example, installing Handbrake from the repos would not install the repo package `libavfilter7`, which would break my `ffmpeg` build?

So far, I've tried using the `--provides` or `--replaces` `checkinstall` options without success. For example:

```bsh
sudo checkinstall -y --deldoc=yes --requires=libc6,libsdl2-2.0-0 --pkgversion=10:$ffmpeg_version  --provides=ffmpeg,libavcodec58,libavdevice58,libavfilter7,libavformat58,libavresample4,libavutil56,libpostproc55,libswresample3,libswresample3,ffmpeg-doc
```

Comment: Packages that depend on the repository ffmpeg may expect a certain API version and configuration.

Answer (score 2):

You're on the right track. The issue is that if any of the packages you install specify dependencies with version numbers, you'll need to specify matching versions in the `--provides` parameter. For example:

```
checkinstall --provides="libavcodec58 \(= x.y.z\),libavdevice58 \(= x.y.z\)"
```

You'll need to use `apt-cache show handbrake` to make sure that the version numbers you specify satisfy the requirements for that package.

[Source](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-relationships.html#virtual-packages-provides)